# toString: When is it used?

Tags: java, tostring

I have a class

```
class Configuration {
  // various stuff

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    // assemble outString
    return outString;
  }
}
```

I also have another class

```
class Log {
  public static void d(String format, Object... d) {
    // print the format using d
  }
}
```

The Log class works perfectly fine, I use it all the time. Now when I do this:

```
Configuration config = getConfiguration();
Log.d(config);
```

I get the compiler error `The method d(String, Object...) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (Configuration)`. I can solve this:

```
Log.d("" + config);       // solution 1
Log.d(config.toString()); // solution 2
```

My problem: How is this different? In the first solution, the compiler notices that it has to concatenate two Strings, but the second one is a Configuration. So `Configuration#toString()` is called and everything is fine. In the compiler error case the compiler sees that a String is needed, but a Configuration is given. Basically the same problem.

- Needed: String
- Given: Configuration

How are these cases different and why is `toString` not called?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something. You have a method that takes a String and optional objects, and you are passing in a Configuration. Therefore you have an error. In the solution cases you are passing in a string and you don't have an error? Isn't that expected?

Comment: @ipavlic Exactly. Why is that expected? The message states clearly, that he has chosen the correct method to match against the given parameters.

Comment: @brimborium: except the parameter does not have the correct type.

Comment: Who has chosen the correct method? There is only one method `d` that you mentioned, and it is the only one called. However, a `Configuration` is not a `string` and Java will not implicitly cast it to be a `string`.

Comment: @ipavlic Ok, I see. I am just used to do `System.out.println(someObject);`. But I just saw, that `println()` takes an Object and not a String as input and calls `toString` on that. So I guess I have to do the same to get the same behaviour.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While designing the language, someone decided that when a programmer appends an arbitrary object to a string using the + operator, they definitely want a `String`, so implicitly calling `toString()` makes sense.

But if you call an arbitrary method that takes a `String` with something else, that is simply a type error, exactly what all that static typing is *supposed* to prevent.

Comment: Oh, I see. So if I want that behaviour, I should have a method `Log#d(Object x, Object... args)`? Which internally calls the `toString` on x?

Comment: Ok, thanks. Works like a charm. :) I accept this answer as most helpful, but if someone has the same problem: the other answers are also quite helpful. ;)

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
"" + config
```

gets translated to something like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
sb.append(config);
```

where the second line calls

```
StringBuilder.append(Object obj);
```

This method calls `obj.toString()` to get the String representation of the object.

On the other hand, the first parameter of `Log.d` must be a String, and Java doesn't automatically call `toString()` to cast everything to a String in that case.

Answer (score 2):

In one case you are passing an object argument to an operator which expects objects.

In the earlier case you are passing an object argument to a function which expects string.

Basically function/operator signature is different.

It is almost incidental [in the context of this question] that .tostring called when + is applied. It takes an object and does something.

For all you know, you might be passing in object when string is required by mistake. So it can't blindly do .tostring()

Answer (score 2):

One of the common use of `toString()`, is `print()` and `println()` methods of `PrintStream`, as in:

```
System.out.print(object);
System.out.println(object);
```

Basically, these two methods will call `toString()` on the passed object. This is one of the [Polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)'s benefits.

Answer (score 2):

Nice Question...

But,
Compiler does not call a method to match formal parameters. it simply tries to cast the objects if possible.

But when you use the "+" operator the compiler executes the toString() method of its arguments (in case they are objects) by default.

Answer (score 1):

`You are passing Configuration  class object argument   in case 1 but in the case 2 , you are passing string argument   . so no error occures`.